# Warning: mysqli_stmt:: bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement when calling stored procedure

Tags: php, stored-procedures, mysqli

I'm trying to call a stored procedure that inserts a new record and returns the last id.
When I call the page I receive the above-mentioned error, with a reference to line 6.

```
$Str = 'Hello world';
$parentId = 1;

$lastId = 0;
$statement = $con->prepare('call createRecordReturnsId( ? , ? )');
$statement->bind_param("si",$Str,$parentId);
$statement->bind_result($lastId);
$statement->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had to move the bind statement (line 7) to after the execute statement (line 8)

The following order works:

```
$Str = 'Hello world';
$parentId = 1;
 
$lastId = 0;
$statement = $con->prepare('call createRecordReturnsId( ? , ? )');
$statement->bind_param("si",$Str,$parentId);
$statement->execute();
$statement->bind_result($lastId);
```

The right order of operations is important, because when calling a stored procedure, mysqli does not know the number of variables that will be returned until the statement is executed.